# design report using visual studio 2013 report designer - how to begin?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013, report-designer

years ago i designed a corporate tool consisting of a sql server 2008 database as backend and an ms access 2007 project file as frontend.

now i build a wpf / c# application using visual studio 2013 to replace ms access 2007.

one of the task is to redesign the existing ms access reports (nothing special - just logos, images, title, subreports etc). but i do not understand how to do it using report designer.

could you please suggest me an article / text / link / walkthrough a ***beginner*** could start with and design a report equivalent to ms access one ?

thank you in advance !

av

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a great aticle to begin with, MSDN is a fantastic resource:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb649551.aspx

Failing that, this is a video that should put you on the way to what you are trying to achieve:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I5UyQHj8jL4

Comment: dear sam, thank you for the quick answer ! will look through. in fact i am not so optimistic about msdn. i spent all the day surfing it but it vain ... ( or it is friday and i am just tired ... ? ) av